TX and RX texts on sim800c on a sim that isnt payg
Well I managed to send and receive texts on one of my sims but my smarty sim (three network), doesnt like it and so I followed the right steps to find out why:
(see what networks are available and auto connect or manual connect. I also found from smartys website that there is reception here)
sendCommand("AT+COPS=?");
+COPS: (3,"vodafone","voda UK","23415"),(3,"T-Mobile","TMO UK","23430"),,(0-4),(0-2)
so smarty also uses vodafone so below
sendCommand("AT+COPS=1,2,\"23415\""); // 
sendCommand("AT+CREG?"); // Check network registration

The code is fine as it worked with my other sim - is there anything I need to know here that anyone could tell me as you guys have more experience. Please.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// com3
/*
  Check Network Compatibility: Ensure that the SIM800C module supports the frequency 
  bands used by Smarty. The SIM800C typically supports quad-band frequencies 
  (850/900/1800/1900MHz), which should cover most networks.
  = yes 900

  Manual Network Registration: Try manually registering on the Smarty network using 
  the correct MCCMNC (Mobile Country Code and Mobile Network Code). You can find this 
  information on Smarty's website or by contacting their customer support.
  = 23415
*/
SoftwareSerial sim800(7, 8); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sim800.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  
  // Initialize communication
  sendCommand("AT");
  sendCommand("AT&F");  // Factory reset
  sendCommand("AT&W");  // Save settings
  sendCommand("AT+CMGF=1");  // Set SMS mode to text
  sendCommand("AT+CSQ"); // Check signal quality
  // sendCommand("AT+COPS=?");
  // +COPS: (3,"vodafone","voda UK","23415"),(3,"T-Mobile","TMO UK","23430"),,(0-4),(0-2)
  // so smarty also uses vodafone so below
  // sendCommand("AT+COPS=1,2,\"23415\""); // 
  sendCommand("AT+CREG?"); // Check network registration

  sendSMS("+1234", "Arduino hobbyist");
}

void sendCommand(const char* command) {
  sim800.println(command);
  delay(1000);
  printResponse();
}

void sendSMS(String number, String message) {
  sendCommand("AT+CMGF=1");  // Ensure text mode
  sim800.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  sim800.print(number);
  sim800.println("\"");
  delay(2000); // Wait for the > prompt
  printResponse();

  sim800.print(message);
  delay(1000);
  sim800.write(26);  // CTRL+Z to send the message
  delay(5000); // Wait for the message to be sent
  printResponse();
}

void printResponse() {
  while (sim800.available()) {
    Serial.write(sim800.read());
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Only monitor responses, do not send messages in loop
  if (sim800.available()) {
    Serial.write(sim800.read());  // Read from SIM800 and write to Serial Monitor
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    sim800.write(Serial.read());  // Read from Serial Monitor and write to SIM800
  }
}


a SIM card does not do any communication ... it is only an authentication key ... which module is the SIM card plugged  into?

It will be more useful to provide the Serial Monitor output data to see how the SIM800 handshake with the network. Also, you don't need the Arduino to test out the SIM800, all you need is a terminal and manually type out the AT commands. Once that work, you can write your code accordingly.

Of course: ```112:57:12.072 -> AT+CMGF=1
12:57:12.072 -> OK
12:57:13.087 -> AT+CSQ
12:57:13.087 -> +CSQ: 20,0
12:57:13.087 ->
12:57:13.087 -> OK
12:57:14.079 -> AT+CREG?
12:57:14.115 -> +CREG: 0,0
12:57:14.115 ->
12:57:14.115 -> OK
12:57:15.094 -> AT+CMGF=1
12:57:15.126 -> OK
12:57:17.120 -> AT+CMGS="+1234"
12:57:17.166 -> > Arduino hobbyist
12:57:29.836 -> ERROR


sorry thats hard to read - i dont know how to format it in comments. is what i put the same as the handshake debug? it would be good to see more like a tcp handshake.

Use AT+CREG? or AT+COPS? to confirm if the SIM800C module successfully registers on the Smarty network.
+CREG: 0,1 or +CREG: 0,5 indicates successful registration.
